# Can the NuGet v2 API resolve dependencies from multiple repositories?

Tags: c#, nuget

NuGet API v2 fails to resolve my self-hosted package's remote dependencies. Can it be configured to search for them on nuget.org? I need to do this programatically.

```
IPackageRepository repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository(@"\\myserver\MyNugetRepo");
var packageManager = new PackageManager(repo, installationFolder);
packageManager.InstallPackage(package.Identifier, package.Version);
```

Error on line 3:

> Unable to resolve dependency '<my remote dependency>'.

Comment: Can't you set that all up VS options?

Comment: The question's about using NuGet.Core to install packages programmatically. I.e., my C# app references NuGet.Core and runs the above code to find and install a NuGet package.

Comment: Oh. I didn't see that as a requirement in the question